# how to use paint component on a frame that is passed from a different class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am making a game called Mastermind. To create the game board, I am using paintComponent to paint onto a frame that was passed as a parameter from a different class. Why doesn't it print anything besides the back button?

```
public class mastermindColor extends JPanel //running color game
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 150, 75);
    private JButton backButton = new JButton();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    public mastermindColor(final JFrame frame) //creating color game frame
    {
        String back = BorderLayout.CENTER;
        backButton.setText("back");
        frame.add(backButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        backButton.setVisible(true);
        backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() //if back button is selected
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                mastermindRunner run = new mastermindRunner();
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) //printing the game set up
    {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.draw(rect);
    }
```

Comment: Where are you adding the mastermind instance to the frame ?

Comment: I added mastermind to the frame in another class called mastermindRunner and I have an action listener that when the colors button is selected, the program passes the frame to the code above and tries to print out the game board.

Comment: And how are you adding the mastermind instance to the frame ? I think you should not mix containing (of backButton) and custom painting. Doing otherwise you interleave possible problems.

Comment: mastermindColor mc = new mastermindColor(frame); Is this what you mean by how I add the mastermind instance to the frame? And how can I create a backButton if I don't mix them together?

Comment: So there mastermind instance, as component, is never added to the frame hierarchy ? You add the button in the BorderLayout.CENTER that is implied, but you never add mastermind anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by how it is never added to the frame hierarchy, but I'm guessing it isn't? So, how can I add it to the frame hierarchy then?

Comment: Instead of adding the button to the center, you could, as a first step, add it to the north with `frame.add(backButton, BorderLayout.NORTH)` and `frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER)`. Both lines in the mastermindColor constructor. May I add that you code does not suit the generally used style that mimicks the JDK by using CameCase for classes ?

Comment: Ok, I added those two lines to my code. With the CamelCase, I should just capitalize the first words too? And what do you suggest me to do about the problem with the mastermindColor not using the paintComponent?

Comment: The second line adds your component to the component hierarchy. So now the paintMethod should be called. But you may still have a problem of size. What should be the size of your drawing area ? You could override getPreferredSize().

Comment: It still isn't drawing rect, but the backButton still shows. The frame size is 1000, 800. I don't think the size of the drawing area is the problem though. When I first coded this program, I did not reuse the same frame from another class. Instead, I created a totally new window frame to display the color game. And when I did that, it would use the paintComponent and display the game board. But, when I changed the code to reuse the same frame, to make it more efficient, it wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: What the code looks like, now ?

Comment: Could I send my whole code to you through email instead?

Comment: Not very fond of this solution. Could you just update the code in the question to current state ?

Comment: Ok, I edited the code.

Comment: The `JFrame f = new JFrame()` line is useless. When I run your code with a 2 lines main, I just need exapnd the frame with the mouse to see your rectangle.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see it. I'll just try to think of another way to code this, but thank you so much for the help!